# Github custom domain for project pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I've read all the posts about this and still can't get it to work.

Here's my situation:

I have a github repo called "father". Inside that repo I have a branch called "gh-pages" with a CNAME.txt file with - builtbyfather.com. I also have a sample index.html in that branch. You can view it here. http://ajlohman.github.io/father/ Github gh-pages branch https://github.com/ajlohman/father/tree/gh-pages

I have a registered domain name (builtbyfather) through godaddy. In the DNS manager I changed the A host (@) and (www) to point to the github server 204.232.175.78.

When I view www.builtbyfather.com all I get is a 404 github page. I need it to point to the "gh-pages" branch.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly the CNAME file should be named `CNAME`, without any extension.

Comment: Very strange. Still getting the 404.